# Name for this Product-Rule Generalisation

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I've stumbled on a nice identity which seems like it would be well-known, and I would like to know more about it, but I can only express it in non-standard notation so I can't look it up. Let $M$ be an $a$ by $b$ matrix and $N$ be an $a$ by $c$ matrix so that $M^T$ and $N$ are compatible. Then we have a generalisation of the dot product $\cdot$ given by by $M\cdot N=M^TN$. Suppose that $f,g:\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$ are differentiable. Then for $x\in\mathbb{R}^m$, $d{(f\cdot g)}_x=df_x\cdot g(x)+dg_x\cdot f(x)$. To verify the identity consider the case $m=1$ and see that this is just a restatement of the partial derivative product rule gives this identity, then generalise the proof of the dot product rule for $n=1$. Note that, unlike in the special cases, $\cdot$ is not commutative, so the only cosmetic change that can be made is swapping the summands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The particular phrasing you've brought up in terms of transposes does not have a name, as far as I know. This is because it's a special case of the
[Leibniz Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule) for products of matrices.

That is, for matrices $\mathbf{A}(x)$ and $\mathbf{B}(x)$, we have
$d(\mathbf{A} \mathbf{B}) = \mathbf{A} \frac{d\mathbf{B}}{dx} + \frac{d\mathbf{A}}{dx} \mathbf{B}$.

This is because the standard proof of the Leibniz Rule relies only on the commutativity of $+$, not of multiplication! This means the identity is still true in the case of matrices (as you've noticed).

You might be interested more generally in [matrix calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus), which explores other identities of this form. This particular identity can be found in the "matrix by scalar identities" section